# Javascript display block not displaying successfully because of django condition

Tags: javascript, django

By default, `request.user.enlazado = True`

Then,

Without page reloading I am setting `request.user.enlazado = False`

Then, this line of code gets executed:

`document.querySelector('#enlazacion').style.display = 'block';`

And this is my html:

```
<section id="enlazacion">
{% if request.user.enlazado is False %}
          <h3>Enlaza</h3>
{% endif %}
</section>
```

The problem is that, as I'm not reloading the page, the front-end still thinks that `request.user.enlazado`  is `True`, while in the server it has already been changed to `False`. That `style.display = 'block'` is not displaying it's content as a result.

Is there a way to override this Django html condition?

Comment: How/where are you setting `request.user.enlazado = False`?

Comment: I am receiving IPN's. From a different view, when the ipn comes, i set `request.user.enlazado = False`

Comment: Have you tried using an AJAX call?